# Rails - How do Controllers pass instance variables to Views...can it be stopped?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I understand and appreciate that by putting @ in front of a variable name in a Controller that it becomes available in whatever View is loaded.  This is wonderfully useful, but I would like to understand the magic.  How does it happen, and can it be stopped?

I am trying to DRY my CRUDdy resource controllers using inheritance, placing most of the logic in `ApplicationController`.  The superclass should refer to the abstract variables `@resource` (for a single resource), `@resources` (for a collection of resources), and `@parent_resource` (for the parent resource when `@resource` is nested), but ideally the view would get more concrete names, for example;`@customer`, `@customers`, and `@sales_territory` respectively.  Can this be done without sending duplicates of all objects (once in the abstract name, and once in the concrete name) to the view?

As I write this, the possibilities that come to mind are;

1. protected instance variables...does Ruby have such a thing, and
   if so does the Controller magic hand them to the View?
2. setting the generic named variables to nil before render/redirect
3. using a protected empty method defined in the subclass to instead of
   abstract named instance variables

What is the right choice in how to implement this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by hiding/blocking these variables from being used in the view? The objects held by the instance variables aren't being 'duplicated' in the view - they are simply accessible to the view by calling instance variables of the controller that have already been set.

Comment: I should have actually put some code to make things more clear, but my goal was to get an answer about the inner workings of the relationship between Views and Controllers in Rails, not a solution to my specific problem.  In my specific case, the superclass was working on '@resource' but the 'CustomersController' needed '@customer' to go to the view. If both of those exist, then my assumption is they both get sent, which would be a waste of resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I'm assuming is happening here, is that there's a bunch of controllers in your app that literally just do the same thing and so you are wanting to make use of inheritance to DRY it up.

That being said, I'm not entirely sure the ApplicationController is the right place to dump all of this functionality as in the future if you had new controllers, they would also inherit all of this functionality without necessarily needing it.

I would do something like this:

- Assuming you have controllers like this:

  - lions_controller.rb
  - tigers_controller.rb
  - hippos_controller.rb

and they pretty much have similar functionality... I would create a "Base" controller and then setup inheritance on child controllers. I would then also make an action that sets the "logical" defaults of child controllers, something like this.

AnimalsController.rb

```
class AnimalsController < ApplicationController
  class_attribute :resource_class, :parent_resource_class

  protected
    def self.set_resource_attributes(options={})
       self.resource_class = options[:resource_class]
       self.parent_resource_class = options[:parent_resource_class]
    end
end
```

LionsController.rb

```
class LionsController < AnimalsController
  #call methods in AnimalsController here, start with setting the resource name
  set_resource_attributes :resource_class => Lion, :parent_resource_class => Animal
end
```

and so on and so forth... the other thing that may be useful is to make use of the methods "instance_variable_set" so that you can set instance variable names in the view that actually make sense... You can make use of the class variables you just set to do this... so for example, lets re-open the AnimalsController.rb class:

```
class AnimalsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    instance_variable_set("@#{self.resource_class.name.underscore}".to_sym, self.resource_class.find(params[:id]))
    #... all the regular show stuff
  end
end
```

This way, when you go to the lions#show path, what you will get in your view is access to a variable named `@lion` which will be set and contain an instance of the Lion class found through ActiveRecord.

Of course this pseudo code I threw in here can be cleaned up and DRY'd a bit more, but hopefully you get where I'm going with it. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: of course since you also have the "parent_resource_class" you can also set instances of it into an instance variable using instance_variable_set in the same way. For more info on instance_variable_set check here: http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Object/instance_variable_set

Comment: Thank you very much.  This answer highlights that I am just not thinking about things in a Ruby way while helping with my specific issue, and pointing me in the right direction with research.  As to the ApplicationController - I started moving code out of there right after posting my question.  Right now all my controllers are straight CRUDdy, but I know that will change going down the line.  I suppose that all this should move to a mix-in, something else I need to teach my self about.